# route for nested model with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, simple-form

I have a `Proposal` Model, which has_one `Quote`.

I'm using simple_form to create both objects at the same time.
The thing is, I want the quote to be a clone of another quote, that belongs to another model `Brief`. In my controller, this looks like that:

```
def new
    @proposal = Proposal.new
    @brief = Brief.find(params[:brief_id])
    @proposal.brief = @brief
    @invoice_quote_element = @brief.invoice_quote_element.deep_clone include: [ :expense_categories, { expense_categories: :expenses } ]
end
```

In my view, I add the form with

```
<%= simple_form_for [@proposal.brief, @proposal, @invoice_quote_element] do |f| %>
```

But this does not work, and I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `brief_proposal_invoice_quote_elements_path'
```

My routes seem clean to me:

```
  resources :proposals do
    resources :invoice_quote_element
    member do
      get 'edit_legal'
      patch 'update_legal'
      get 'quote'
      get 'view_quote'
      get 'download_quote'
    end
  end
```

Now, if I remove the @invoice_quote_element from the simple_form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@proposal.brief, @proposal] do |f| %>
```

The form displays just fine, but I cannot submit it, because the `create` method raises a new error:

```
Couldn't find InvoiceQuoteElement with ID=299 for Proposal with ID=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the `:url` param in the form, `Rails FormHelper` will use `polymorphic_path` to generate form action url. For more information you can visit [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html). You get the first error because the path is not defined. When you removed the `@invoice_quote_element`, the generated path will be `brief_proposals_path`, which is perhaps defined in your routes file, so it works. But when you submitted the form, Rails will run the method `create` of controller `proposals`, which may cause error. You should check the log to know which controller and action are called. In your case, I think `<%= simple_form_for [@proposal, @invoice_quote_element] do |f| %>` should work.

Comment: Well, for some reason, it doesn't. I thought of it, I added the matching resources in my routes, but when I turn it to <%= simple_form_for [@proposal, @invoice_quote_element] do |f| %>, I get this : undefined method `proposal_invoice_quote_elements_path' . I don't understand why invoice_quote_elements is a plural, while proposal has only one attached to it.

Comment: The `@ invoice_quote_element` is nil so the invoice_quote_elements is plural, as `it recognizes new records and maps to the collection` in the link above. You change the resources to `resources :invoice_quote_elements` and it should work.

Comment: Indeed, it worked ! Now it raises a new error: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"invoice_quote_elements", :proposal_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:proposal_id] , which is quite normal since we're on ```proposals#new```, and therefore proposal has no id yet...

Comment: The nested routes should only be used to edit invoice_quote_element. In this case, you should use `form_for @proposal' and 'fields_for :invoice_quote_elements`

Comment: Well, no more errors, the invoice_quote_element gets saved, everything works fine, last thing I have to do is found how to prefill the invoice_quel_element fields with the attributes from another InvoiceQuoteElement. Thantks a lot !